# How to show that $a_n^c\to 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)_n$ be a sequence of non-negative real numbers such that $a_n\to0$ and $c>0.$ How to show that $a_n^c\to0?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $f\colon [0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ defined by $f(x) = x^c$ is continuous.

**Second hint:** $f(0)=0$.

Comment: Why is this continuous?

Comment: Depending on what you have seen so far, it is more or less obvious.Power functions are continuous.

Comment: Using the definition of continuity how that can be shown?

Comment: Which definition of continuity do you start with (there are several, equivalent), and how did you define $x^c$ for $x>0$ and $c>0$ non-integer?

Answer (score 0):

Assume first that all $a_{n}$ are positive, then $c\log a_{n}\rightarrow c\cdot-\infty=-\infty$, so $a_{n}^{c}=e^{c\log a_{n}}\rightarrow 0$. For nonnegative $a_{n}$, we have $a_{n}^{c}\leq(a_{n}+1/n)^{c}\rightarrow 0$, so Squeeze Theorem yields the result.